Make VMware assign a static IP address to your machine
So, I used to be able to do this thing, where my VMs would have a static IP address assigned when i created them. They had access to the internet, and I distinctly remember that it always sets your gateway to xxx.xxx.xxx.2.
I'm running VMWare workstation. I also remember I didn't need to go Virtual Network Editor to do it, it took minimal setup but I just don't remember what it was. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you want to use DHCP reservation for VMs using NAT, see Assigning fixed IP by DHCP in VMWare Workstation.
